# du vs df output

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

Why are there differences between the outputs of the `df` and `du` commands?

Why they are not accurate in output?

```
# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3 1012M 394M 567M 42% /
/dev/sda2 99M 47M 48M 50% /boot
/dev/sda8 9.9G 1.5G 7.9G 16% /home
none 1004M 0 1004M 0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda9 347G 93G 236G 29% /srv
/dev/sda11 2.0G 81M 1.8G 5% /tmp
/dev/sda10 4.0G 1.3G 2.6G 33% /usr
/dev/sda6 4.0G 2.1G 1.8G 55% /usr/local
/dev/sda5 20G 19G 0 100% /var
```

However, if I do a `du -sh /var` it reports that only 4.6G are being used:

```
# du -sh /var
4.6G /var
```

Answer (score 8):

> The standard cause for this is **some
>   user process keeping a deleted file
>   open**. When this happens, the **space is
>   not visible via ‘du’**, since the file
>   is no longer visible in the directory
>   tree. However, the space is still used
>   by the file until it is deallocated,
>   and that can only happen once the last
>   process which has the file open either
>   closes its file descriptor to the
>   file, or the process exits. You can
>   use the **lsof** program to try to find
>   which process is keeping an open file.
>   Usually it’s some log file, or some
>   large data base file which gets
>   rotated out, but some older process
>   are still keeping the log file open.

**source** : [‘df’ command VS ‘du’ command](http://gcolpart.evolix.net/blog21/df-command-vs-du-command/)

Answer (score 4):

Ttry this:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-why-command-df-and-du-reports-different-output.html
 If the files are deleted (by rm command) while they are being opened or used by a Linux program / process, the evil of "open file descriptor" problem arises and confuse the Linux file system on reporting the real figure of used disk space or free disk space available.

In order to resolve the fake "disk space full" problem, i.e. to reclaim "used disk space", you need to kill or terminate the "defunct process" - in this case, the rm command that turns to be defunct process while the files are being used.

Once these defunct processes are terminated, the "open file descriptor" problem will be resolved, and both the du and df commands will agree to report the real file system used disk space or free disk space!

How to find out and terminate or kill the defunct processes that cause open file descriptor problem, in order to resolve the difference of used disk space in du and df command?

For this particular scenario, the lsof command (list open file command) is great to show light:

```
#lsof | grep "deleted"
```

and look for Linux process ID in second column of the lsof command output. The seventh column is the size of file being "deleted" (but not success and turns out to be defunct process).

Now, you'll just need to kill the Linux process IDs to see the correct ouput of DU and DF, Use following command to kill the Process IDs

```
#lsof | grep "deleted" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Now verify the disk usage by both commands; you should not get the difference.

Comment: Here's a slightly less dangerous listing command:

lsof | grep "deleted" | awk '{print $2}' | uniq | sort | xargs ps -p

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't apply in your case, but in general it's important to remember the `-x` flag to `du`.  Otherwise it might go into other mounted filesystems and certainly won't match `df` output, which by default is per-filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

*This is of course way after the question, so it is more for posterity.*

There can be another (less common but significant) cause for this - mounted directories.

Consider a scenario (e.g. while using FreeBSD jails) where a directory (`/multimedia`) is mounted to a different location (`/usr/something/media`). Now doing a `du` will include the size of the /multimedia directory under the `/usr/something/media` directory, and hence show an inflated size of `/usr`. But `df` will show the true size of `/usr` - excluding the contents of the mounted `/multimedia` directory.