# What is using up this space in Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-space

Here's my output of df -h:

```
[root@box root]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      1.8T  231G  1.5T  14% /
/dev/sda3              92M   27M   61M  31% /boot
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc1             7.6G  6.3G  1.3G  83% /mnt/backup
```

I have a drive plugged in that I use as a backup which is aptly mounted at `/mnt/backup`.  I've been getting errors that I can't copy files to this directory.  So I tried to see what's using up the space, and therein lies the confusing part:

```
[root@box backup]# pwd; ls -a
/mnt/backup
.  ..
```

What's up with that‽  There are no files but 6.3 GB is being used?

Comment: Try checking the file system.

Comment: Show the output of `du -s /mnt/*` or `du -s `/mnt/backup/*`.

Comment: @ott :
`[root@box backup]# du -sh /mnt/*
4.0K    /mnt/backup`

Comment: Hmm. Could http://superuser.com/questions/289678/du-vs-df-output be the answer?