# Folder is empty, but du reports high usage

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, du, df

I have a `115GB` partition on my hard disk (output of `cgdisk /dev/sda` is below):

```
Part. #     Size        Partition Type            Partition Name
----------------------------------------------------------------
            1007.0 KiB  free space
   1        499.0 MiB   Windows RE                Basi
   2        100.0 MiB   EFI System                EFI 
   3        16.0 MiB    Microsoft reserved        Micr
   5        43.9 GiB    Linux filesystem          ubuntu-root
   6        43.9 GiB    Linux filesystem          ubuntu-home
   4        114.9 GiB   Linux filesystem          data         <--- this partition
   7        29.5 GiB    Linux filesystem
```

And I have mounted that partition on `/data` in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=<drive-uuid>  /data  ext4  defaults  0  0
```

When I do `df -h /data`, I have the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       113G   96G   11G  90% /data
```

And when I use `du` like this: `du /data -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr`, I see this:

```
51G    /data
40G    /data/virtual-box
4.4G   /data/temp
4.1G   /data/manjaro-minikube
1.9G   /data/.nuget
764M   /data/OneDrive
62M    /data/manjaro-lxd
40K    /data/.minikube
16K    /data/lost+found
```

which, if I'm not mistaken, is showing that `/data` is taking `51G` and then I have the `virtual-box`, `temp`, `manjaro-minikube`, and `.nuget` directories taking space (the other ones don't take significant space)

If I do a long listing of my directory (`ls -alh /data`):

```
total 68K
drwxr-xr-x  10 farzad farzad 4.0K Aug 13 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 root   root   4.0K Jul 13 10:32 ..
drwx------   2 farzad farzad  16K Mar 22 18:22 lost+found
drwx--x--x  15 root   root   4.0K Aug 20 17:47 manjaro-lxd
drwxr-xr-x   3 farzad farzad 4.0K Jul  3 18:16 manjaro-minikube
drwxrwxr-x   9 farzad farzad 4.0K Jul 30 17:38 .minikube
drwxr-xr-x 202 farzad farzad  16K Aug 17 10:00 .nuget
drwxr-xr-x   3 farzad farzad 4.0K Aug 13 21:47 OneDrive
drwxrwxr-x  16 farzad farzad 4.0K Jun  3 21:45 temp
drwxr-xr-x   6 farzad farzad 4.0K Aug 20 20:21 virtual-box
```

I don't see any file or something contributing to that `51G` reported for `/data`, so I expect my drive to  have almost `65G` empty space, but for some reason, the `/data` parent directory is taking `51G` by itself!

I tried researching the Internet, but I couldn't find anything. Can someone please let me know what's happening?

---

UPDATE

As suggested in the answers, I ran `lsof /data | grep deleted` (as root), but I don't have any result, although I see a warning, which I'm not sure is relevant:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that there were a few issues here (thank you @Kamil for helping to find them):

Although this was my initial intuition that the amount reported by `du` for `/data` is the sum of all its child directories (with some rounding), I guess I was trying to justify the discrepancies between `df` and `du` and thought that I should sum up `du`'s output for `/data` and all its child directories to get the same result as `df`.

The other issue, which is the main one causing the discrepancies, was because of how I had configured my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=<uuid>  /data  ext4  defaults  0  0
                                       ^
                                     ISSUE
```

When I created my `/etc/fstab`, I thought that I wouldn't need to prolong my startup by enabling file system checks (`fsck`) on my mount, hence `0` for the sixth field, but as it turned out, is was causing inodes not be cleaned up, hence causing the BIG difference between `df` and `du`.

So, looking at `man 5 fstab`, we can see that, in order to enable checks, the root file system should have value `1`, and other file systems should have value `2`, so I changed the line to be:

```
UUID=<uuid>  /data  ext4  defaults  0  2
```

And after restart, a lot of issues were reported by `fsck`, I chose to fix them, and now the output of `du /data -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr`:

```
28G    /data
16G    /data/virtual-box
4.5G   /data/temp
4.1G   /data/manjaro-minikube
1.9G   /data/.nuget
824M   /data/OneDrive
64M    /data/manjaro-lxd
40K    /data/.minikube
16K    /data/lost+found
```

And output of `df /data -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       113G   28G   80G  26% /data
```

It's worth noting that, compared to my original question, I have removed a few files (hence `28G` usage instead of `51G`), but the good thing is that both `du` and `df` report the same value :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `/data` is taking `51G`. This includes all subdirectories and files within it. If you add sizes reported by `du` for subdirectories (and consider rounding issues), you will get about `51G`. If there were regular files directly in `/data`, they would contribute to the value reported for `/data` as well.

So `du` does not report high usage. It's `df` what reports high usage: `96G` is in use in the filesystem.

Since `/data` is a mountpoint, you may expect the two values to be the same. But the two tools work differently: `du` traverses directories and adds sizes of encountered objects, `df` queries the filesystem about its knowledge of its own state.

Such big discrepancy may be because:

- `du` was not able to get to (or get info about) all objects. Was there any `permission denied` error?
- There is inconsistency in the filesystem; `fsck.ext4` aka `e2fsck` may help.
- (**most likely**) There is at least one file that was deleted (all directory entries pointing to the respective inode was removed, the file doesn't appear in any directory listing so `du` cannot know about it) but it's still in use by some process (so the filesystem keeps the data and takes it into account while reporting to `df`). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/289680/432690), [this question](https://superuser.com/q/489671/432690).

  The following command should find such files and processes using them:

  ```
  lsof /data | grep deleted
  ```

  Example output:

  ```
  some_daemon  …  …  …  …  …  …  …  /data/temp/huge_file (deleted)
  ```

  This means the filesystem will truly delete the `huge_file` only after `some_daemon` stops using it. Note in general the process can still append to the file or truncate it, so the file may grow or shrink. This will affect what `df` says, but not `du`.

Comment: Thank you @Kamil for your reply, I tried your command and updated the question. Do you have any idea how I can track down what's happening?

Comment: @Farzad You should check the filesystem. Run `e2fsck -f /dev/sda4` after unmounting; or schedule the check with `tune2fs` (e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/108618)) so it happens during reboot. After you confirm the filesystem is healthy and in a consistent state, run `df` and `du` again. Please report if the discrepancy is still there, edit the question if needed.

Comment: Thank you @Kamil, I modified my `/etc/fstab` to add `fsck` to the file system, and I'm somehow "shocked" by how much more available space it reports now :). I didn't want to take credit for what you suggested, so I didn't "answer" my question. Please let me know what we can do for the answer.

Comment: @Farzad Frankly I *did not* notice there is `0` in the sixth field in the `fstab` entry. If your answer is going to be like "`0` is bad, it makes `fsck` not run; see `man 5 fstab` and change accordingly (to `2` in this case); after I did this…" (post new output of `df`, `du`) – then **yes!**, add your own answer, because this is new and useful, brings attention to `fstab` where the primary culprit was; it's not an ad-hoc fix, it will prevent similar situations in the future. In your answer you may admit you misinterpreted `du` (I think you did). Accept your answer and I will gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is sorting the results from highest to lowest. The highest value is the *total* space used by `/data`, not the space it has used by itself.